# Pyspark agg max abs val but keep sign

Tags: pyspark

I'm agg on another col. For ex if the col was

```
ID   val
A   10
A   100
A   -150
A    15
B    10
B    200
B    -150
B    15
```

I'd want to return the below (keeping the sign). Not sure how to do this while keeping the sign

```
ID    max(val)
A    -150
B    200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: using a window function + row_number. We parition by `ID` and order by `abs(val)` descending. Then we simply take the first row.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [
    ('A', 10),
    ('A', 100),
    ('A', -150),
    ('A', 15),
    ('B', 10),
    ('B', 200),
    ('B', -150),
    ('B', 15)
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=('ID','val'))

w = Window().partitionBy('ID').orderBy(F.abs('val').desc())

(df
    .withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(w))
    .filter(F.col('rn') == 1)
    .drop('rn')
).show()

+---+----+                                                                      
| ID| val|
+---+----+
|  A|-150|
|  B| 200|
+---+----+
```

Option 2: A solution which works with `agg`. We compare the max value to the absolute max value. If they match then take the max, if they don't then take the min. Note that this solution prefers the positive value in case of ties.

```
df.groupby('ID').agg(
    F.when(F.max('val') == F.max(F.abs('val')), F.max('val')).otherwise(F.min('val')).alias('max_val')
).show()

+---+-------+                                                                   
| ID|max_val|
+---+-------+
|  A|   -150|
|  B|    200|
+---+-------+
```

Comment: would this work with an agg? bc im doing a bunch of other aggs on other cols :(

Comment: it will not work with agg sadly

Comment: I've added a solution which works with `agg`